# If else statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, attr

I am learning JavaScript and I need help as I don't know how to use boolean for your if else statement for an attribute. Please help me, thanks.

I am trying to make my search bar hide and show on click using jQuery.

```
$(function() {

function runEffect() {

var options = {};
var callback = {};
var yo = $("#search").attr("style").hide();

if (yo = false) {
$( "#search" ).hide( 'drop', options, 1000, callback );
}

else{
$("#search").removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
}
}

$("#btnSearch").click(function() { runEffect() 
});
})
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison.

Comment: @elclanrs best to avoid mentioning == to a beginner except in the context of "don't use it", I should have thought.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4c9c91ek/2/  you can see this for boolean https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4c9c91ek/3/\

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if a variable always has a boolean value, it is safe to simply say if (flag) {...} or if (!flag) {...}. No comparison to a static value is necessary

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that chaining .attr("style") with .hide() doesn't make any sense. Also worth mentioning that when you use the statment $("#search").attr("style").hide(), the .hide() returns a jQuery object, which you are then assigning to the 'yo' variable, and then trying to compare if a jQuery object == false, which doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is quite a bit that you are not understanding in terms of jQuery, selection, attributes, and DOM manipulation. I would recommend reading through the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) and the [Learn jQuery Tutorials](https://learn.jquery.com/). Mainly focusing (for this application) on the understanding of how `.attr()`, `:visible`, `.hide()`, and assignment/comparison operators work. Below is a working demo of what you would be looking to do as a reference point:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/05ateqbL/)